# Bilinear form and notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

When I read about the bilinear form, i see this notation:
$$
f: V \times V \to \mathbb{F}
$$ is a bilinear form on $V$ if .....

Can anybody explain to me what this expression is actually saying in maybe language that newbs would understand. I now we are using these expression to be more precise, but can anyone explain what this expression is saying?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation means "a function from $V\times V$ to $F$."

Generally you can say that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ by writing $f:X\to Y$. Here $X$ is the set $V\times V=\{(v,w)\mid v,w\in V\}$.

Then, as you say, it goes on further to specify some properties the function must satisfy. That's all.

Comment: I suppose I'm not understanding the $V \times V$ bit really. Is that a cross product sign?

Comment: @Bucephalus Well, if you mean the cross product of vectors, it looks the same but no it is not the cross product. It signifies the Cartesian product of $V$ with itself.

Comment: Cartesian product of a vector space.. hmmmm. So the set of all dot products of all the vectors in $V$?

Comment: I will go and do some googling of cartesian product. Thanks.

Comment: @Bucephalus No, that is not what it means. I already added an explanation in my post about it right after you asked what it meant.

Comment: to me that means the set of all pairs of vectors in $V$. Is that what you added means? $(v,w)$ ?

Comment: thanks, do you mean they are simply pairs of vectors consisting of the vectors in $V$?

Comment: @Bucephalus Yes. Your googling on "Cartesian product" should confirm that. And it makes sense, right? It's a function that associates an element of $F$ to each pair of elements of $V$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now @rschwieb. Thanks for your help.